# Компьютер включается сам после гибернации (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Когда я ухожу спать, я нажимаю кнопку Sleep на клавиатуре и компьютер переходит в спящий режим, но иногда он внезапно включается без каких-либо причин! Раньше я думал, что проблема в клавиатуре, у меня слегка залипает клавиша альт, думал что компьютер включается из за неё, но сейчас заметил, что это происходит как правило по утрам! Честно говоря, очень раздражает такое поведение, особенно когда он будит меня. Проблема актуальна на Ubuntu GNOME 17.04, но раньше (довольно давно) я пользовался Xubuntu и с ним происходило тоже самое.

**UPD:** в общем, я пробовал некоторое время отключать клавиатуру и мышь после перевода в спящий режим и в те дни компьютер сам не включался, но это ещё не показатель. Сегодня и позавчера компьютер включился ровно в **10:00** и **5:00** утра. При этом он разбудил меня относительно громким шумом. Я посмотрел в системыный монитор и самым прожорливым из незнакомых мне процессов был `gsd-housekeeping`, он задействовал около 100 мб памяти.
Понятия не имею, что этот плагин делает; попробую его отключить.

Comment: сам собой всплыл [анекдот про реанимацию и уборщицу с пылесосом](http://anekdotov.me/medicina-i-zdorove/66754-v-reanimacionnom-otdelenii-bolnicy-no6-na-6-m.html). // вы можете провести простой эксперимент: отключите все периферийные устройства и дождитесь утра.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin я попробую, но проблема в том, что компьютер включается не каждый день. Может раз в неделю, иногда чаще, иногда реже.

Comment: Зависит от модели компьютера, версии ядра и пр., а вы не предоставили эту информацию.

Comment: @0andriy я сказал, что сменил дистрибутив, а проблема осталась. Да и вообще, я довольно часто обновляю ядро, т.е. версия ядра вряд ли имеет значение. А по поводу модели компьютера... Ну это не ноутбук, нет у него "модели". Какое конкретно железо может оказывать такое воздействие?

Comment: Ядро имеет отношение самое непосредственное, как и внутренние пошивки. Про то, что это не ноутбук вы упомянули только сейчас. О чём я и говорил -- если человек хочет, чтобы ему помогли, будет искать способы...

Comment: @0andriy так я и ищу способы! На данный момент пытаюсь засечь это явление с отключённой периферией. Пока безрезультатно, так что видимо проблема в ней. Ядро никак не может влиять, поскольку от момента, когда я использовал xubuntu, до сегодняшнего дня, я успел обновить ядро наверное раз 100 (ну или сколько раз его обновляли за 2 года?). Вы не читаете что я вам пишу и предъявляете ко мне какие-то претензии.

Comment: Нет никаких претензий, просто без деталей ваш вопрос напоминает "подземный стук".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причиной этому может быть внешний UCB носитель либо мышка, либо клавиатура, предлагаю отключить пробуждение от них. Командой

```
grep enabled /proc/acpi/wakeup|cut -f1|sudo tee /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

Перед тем как выполнить эту команду лучше взгляните на этот файл.

```
"/proc/acpi/wakeup"
```

После выполнение команды выше описанной , ПК будет просыпаться только от кнопки питания

Comment: Я посмотрел `/proc/acpi/wakeup` перед выполнением ваше команды, там всё выключено, кроме USB0 и USB2. Затем я ввёл команду и отключилось USB0. USB2 по-прежнему осталось включенным! После чего я решил ради эксперимента перезагрузиться, и, как я и предполагал, после перезагрузки действие вашей команды сбросилось. USB0 и USB2 снова включены.

Comment: /proc - это виртуальня файловая система хронящаяся в озу. она обнуляется с выключением питания.  не проще просто отсоединить мышку?

Comment: В биосе посмотрите, не задан ли там параметр авто включения

Comment: @Артур нет, не задан.

Comment: @Hellseher отсоединять мышь и клавиатуру каждый день? Проще уж тогда не пользоваться гибернацией вообще, но это не решение проблемы.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, если вы знаете, может ли компьютер "просыпаться" по другим причинам? По расписанию или сетевому запросу? Дело в том, что я не уверен, что проблема в клавиатуре/мыши. Почему-то я наблюдал такое только по утрам.